# SIP keyboard sometimes does not show up?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, keyboard, show, soft-keyboard

I have a `TextBox` in my Windows Phone 7 page. When I touch on it, some times the SIP keyboard doesnot show up. I encounter this on my C900 phone.

Don't know if this is a problem with WP7, or just my phone. How to handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your screen is greased over and needs a cleaning OR you may have re-sized your TextBox control too small. Try both, hopefully it's not a hardware related issue.